# Electron build error

Tags: electron

I'm trying to build an app made with electron but when a build the Windows version this error appears on console and the screen stay blank:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/8track/resources/app.asar/index.html

If I set webSecurity as false this error disappear but the blank screen continues.
I have tried the solution of this issue in GitHub and even setting "asar" as false in package.json without success.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What tool do you use to build your app/how do you build your app? Since the github ticket is about webpack, can we assume that you use webpack? Could you add more information about your setup?

Comment: We are using electron-builder to build the distributable package. Running npm run electron:windows to build for windows. NPM scripts on the link below.

https://codeshare.io/5Mg7EO

Comment: Ok, could you also add your webpack.config.js? (it is better you add every additional information to your question instead of linking in the comments as they are not save from deletion). Also: could you post the line where you load the html in your window? Do you use __dirname in that line?